# Is there a way to customize SMS quick text?

Tags: sms

I have an LG Ally.  I have a market SMS popup app that lets me customize the quick text, but that only works if someone texts you first and it pops up.  Sometimes I need to sent a quick text to someone that hasn't texted me first, such as "driving" or "call you in a minute".  The stock quick texts on the Ally messaging app are pretty lame, and I haven't been able to figure out a way to customize them.

Answer (score 3):

The [Handcent SMS app](http://www.handcent.com/) allows for custom template messages.

Comment: Is it a popup app or does it take the place of the app that came on the phone?

Comment: You can have it popup and it works in conjunction with the app on the phone.  You can disable notifications from one of the apps so that you don't get 2 per message.

Comment: I guess you can't have it all!  I liked the other popup app because you could customize notifications for contacts.  Handcent SMS doesn't allow that.  Oh, well....

Comment: You could probably suggest that feature to Handcent though.  Worth a shot anyways

Comment: FYI...I discovered Go SMS app.  It allows you to customize contact notifications, customize quick text, and download Thumbplay ringtones...YAHTZEE!

Comment: Can I install Handcent SMS, modify existing SMS Templates, uninstall Handcent SMS, and then continue using the modified SMS Templates?